# Can't come up with the correct sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have some trouble coming up with the right sentence for a form input where I'm asking a user's first and last name.

What I'm actually trying to say is that the name the user is filling in will be used to name this person, in for example emails.

Right now I have:

> We will reference to you by this name.

But it doesn't sound right to me, and I think it isn't.

Comment: The verb you are looking for is *refer*. "We will refer to you by this name."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the passive, and say:

> *[You will be referred to by this name](http://media.jsonline.com/documents/Battle+of+the+Bridesmaids+5+additional+rules.doc)*.
>
> *[You will be addressed by this name](https://webapps.ou.edu/scsymposium/)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say:

*We will address you as Mr....*

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthroponym 
Antroponyms are names for Persons.

You could theoretically say we'll anthroponymize you as follows:

Or Josh61 answer is good too. We'll be adressing or reffering to you by the following name:

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more explanatory option:

> This is the name we'll use in future communication with you.